# Google Api getting an error

Tags: ios, google-oauth

```
NSString *clientsec = @"my client sec";
NSString *clientid = @"client id";
NSString *grant = @"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1";

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"client_secret=%@&grant_type=%@&client_id=%@",clientsec,grant,clientid];

NSLog(@"%@",post);
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

i am posting the data like this but i am getting an error like this

```
 "error" : "invalid_request"
```

can any one solve my problem ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This google API must contain 5 arguments.

```
code - The authorization code returned from the initial request 
client_id - The client_id obtained during application registration 
client_secret - The client secret obtained during application registration 
redirect_uri - The URI registered with the application 
grant_type - As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field must contain a value of authorization_code
```

Then your actual request might look like this

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

So you have to add **code** and **redirect_uri** parameters in your request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Manujmv how to add the CODE and REDIRECT_URI parameters

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this one, and worked:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSString *clientsec = @"my client sec";
NSString *clientid = @"client id";
NSString *grant = @"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1";
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"client_secret=%@&grant_type=%@&client_id=%@",clientsec,grant,clientid];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [postData length]];

urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest* theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:120.0f];

[theRequest setURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",responseData);
```

**Output:**

> client_secret=my client
>   sec&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1&client_id=client
>   id 2013-12-10 19:10:07.283 AkbarVenkatConflict[18969:8c03] <7b0a2020
>   22657272 6f722220 3a202269 6e76616c 69645f63 6c69656e 74222c0a
>   20202265 72726f72 5f646573 63726970 74696f6e 22203a20 22426164
>   20726571 75657374 2e220a7d>

Comment: Thanks for your reply i tried your code and this is my output 
<7b0a2020 22657272 6f722220 3a202269 6e76616c 69645f72 65717565 7374220a 7d>
converting nsdata to nsstring {
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
to convert nsdata to nsstring i worte this code

NSString *status = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"converting nsdata to nsstring %@",status);

Comment: yes. there is something wrong in the url or request body, as you are getting a clear response.

Comment: Thanks for responding i am posting clinet_secret and client_id and grant_type but the responce is invalid_request .Is there any other parameters i want to pass the google